# After deleting from items array there is a problem with the ID that resulted from Url.findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```js
app.post('/delete', function (req, res) {
  const checkedItemId = req.body.check
  const listName = req.body.listName
  mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false)
  if (listName === 'today') {
    List.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function (err) {
      if (err) console.log(err)
      else {
        console.log('deleted succesfully')
        res.redirect('/') //to refresh itself ana delete on the spot
      }
    })
  } else {
    // pull from item array with id

    console.log(checkedItemId)

    // error - delete doesn't work
    Url.findOneAndUpdate(
      { name: listName },
      { $pull: { items: { _id: checkedItemId } } },
      { new: true },
      function (err, result) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        else {
          console.log(result)
          res.redirect('/' + listName)
        }
      }
    )
  }
})

**********************my ejs 


    <form action="/delete" method="post">

      <div class="item">

      <input type="checkbox" name="check" value=<%=element._id %>  
         onChange="this.form.submit()">
        <p> <%=element.name%></p><!-- i am adding only the name inside my db-->

      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="listName" value=<%=theDay%>></input>
        </form>
```

- `listName` is the name of the list I want to choose from my data base
- `items` is the array that I chose my ID from
- `checkedItemId` is the ID of the item I want to remove
- if i changed `value=<%=element._id %>` to `value=<%=element.name %>`
- and in js `items: { _id: checkedItemId }` to `items: { name: checkedItemId }`
- it works with name  but with the id it doen't

Is there any wrong syntax?

Comment: Hi @panda boi! Your question was very hard to read, I edited it. What's missing though is a description of the exact issue you are seeing. Can you describe what the problem with this code is? What do you expect to happen/see, and what happens instead? What is wrong about the ID that you get? Thank you

Comment: thanks  for improving my question , the problem is that there is an item i wanted to delete  that is in items array and the item have an id ,the problem that the id that results from the findOneAndUpdate is wrong  i checked  it by consol.log(result )  and it showed my that it got a wrong id

Comment: Please show the exact code which does what you just mentioned, with the expected and actual output. Like, what values listName, items, checkedItemId are, what database items there are, what the output for `result` is, what you expected instead, etc

Comment: the part of if(listName==="today") is working fine it belongs to the home page the else refer to dynamic routed pages

Comment: Thank you but yet again you omitted the variable values as well as the expected and actual output. Please add them. It is still not clear what behavior you are observing vs. expecting. Also, please show the database schema and an example document of the `Url` collection before and after the update.